# Writing webservice in C/C++

Tags: c, web-services, gsoap

I'm starting to develop a client webservice in C/C++. I don't know which library to use. I've read about Axis2C and gSoap.
Any suggestion for developing a C/C++ SOAP webservice client? It seems that Axis2C is being discontinued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stay away from Axis2.  Use gSOAP.  If the web service is simple, you might also try [wsdlpull](http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/) as it's pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

- See the [gSOAP tutoral](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) for web service creation and consumption in C++.
- It's pretty simple and easy to learn/use.

Note : See the **sample code for calculator web service** creation using gSOAP and the instructions to start the service and consume it by client [HERE](https://github.com/pritam-patil/comp-lab-2/tree/master/web-services-calci).

P.S. : Don't get bullied by seeing too many files. You have to write only {calc.cpp, calc.h and client.cpp}. Other files are generated by gSOAP utility soapcpp2.